# Prevent restart of NestJS Server when making changes in certain directories

Tags: typescript, webpack, nestjs

I am using the default `nest start --watch` command to run the application in watch mode.

The server restarts upon the change of any source file, which is as expected.

However, I need to ignore some directories or files from restarting the server when a change occurs.

Is there a way to achieve this in NestJS?

Comment: I think it starts tsc in watch mode, and you can configure what is going to be ignored in tsc configuration, I think in that case those files are not going to be transpiled to js. So looks like; no there is no way.

Comment: Imo, I'd take a look at what the nest cli does, how it is linked to wepback's config (hot reload feature from it notably I guess). Don't have time to investigate further as of now, will take a look later if you're still stuck

Comment: Hi @A.Maitre, have you had a chance to investigate on this issue yet? My name is Nechar. I am stuck in the same issue as Nik. The solution provided by WRAD did not work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround. That is updated nodemon.json file to include the directories that I want to ignore from restart. Then to start the app I am just running **nodemon** command.

```
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts",  
    "ignore": ["public"],
    "exec": "ts-node ./src/main"
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How about for newer versions of NestJS where nodemon is no longer used?

Comment: @avejidah even if nest does not use nodemon, you can still tsc --watch and use nodemon in development.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by editing tsconfig.build.json file and add the folder to the exclude array.
"exclude": [..., "your-folder"]

Answer (score 0):

You should update following package:

- typescript

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You should edit these files:

- `tsconfig.json`
- `tsconfig.build.json`

Add the folder/s that you want to ignore in the "exclude" array:

`"exclude": [..., "your-folder"]`

Comment: I still would like TypeScript to transpile my .ts files to .js files. I just need to prevent the server from a re-start on few directories.

Comment: The solution that you provided would only help prevent the TS file from being compiled to JS. But it wouldn't stop the server from being restart.